# Software to calculate an integer sum?

Tags: math-software, calculator

There is a result I want to calculate, but I don't know if there is any software that can help me with this. Anyone knows what could I use to help me? Any answer is much appreciated

The formula is this: 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{37}(-1)^{k-14}\binom{k}{14}\binom{37}{k}(37-k)^{37}$$

Any program/software that I can download or use online for this? I'm pretty sure it's more than hard to calculate it without software help.

Comment: Use [wolfram aplha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: can it be caclulated using the free version or must i subscribe for pro?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Just type it in and see what it says :)

Comment: not sure how to write on wolframalpha Σ symbol and combinations but i'll give it a try. hope i can try and find something out

Comment: it's just "sum *your expression* from 0 to 37"

Comment: If you throw this expression `Sum[(-1)^(k-14)*Binomial[k,14]*Binomial[37,k]*(37-k)^37,{k,14,37}]` to WA, it returns the same number as Martin's answer.

Comment: @lovsovs yes thanks! now i calculated it easily. and changed some variables i wanted as well using some help from the answers as well. :)

Comment: @achille hui yes. i also checked with some other variables . thanks everyone for helping me. i love stats and maths but never yet had the chance to study them in bigger depth :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maxima:

`sum((-1)^(k-14) * binomial(k,14) * binomial(37,k) * (37-k)^37,k,0,37);
2102461537664289404445654948320063396409217803878400000000`

Comment: looks good. i'll give it a try for some other variables i want also to test. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use basically any programming language to do the calculations. I'd try python.

Comment: This could be offered as a Comment, but it seems too unspecific to provide as an Answer.  If the OP were not already familiar with doing big-integer programming in Python, details on how to do that might be helpful.